# iPhone installation while app installing

Tags: iphone, file, installation

I'm wondering if it is possible to create files during installation of my iPhone app.

Anyone alreday did this ? How ?

Of course, my files won't be in bundle, only in Documents directory.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you got a bit more info about the type of files you are wanting to create? (i.e. why can't they be shipped with the app, or created on first time app is launched - do they require installation time etc.?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. You can't run any code until the user launches your application.

So you will have to wait until the first time the app is launched to create these files.